# Is it possible to use mongoDB commands such as mongoexport in a bash script run through AWS Lambda?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mongoexport

As the title says, I'm wondering if mongoexport can be used in a bash script run with a Lambda.

I'm trying to read into implementing bash scripts on Lambdas here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html

It is not clear which executable commands are available. Will I be able to use mongoexport in a similar setup to the tutorial?